# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL Result in line 40

Tags: php, html, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

i keep getting the error 
 Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL Result in line 40
on my webpage i dont know why.. please help me .
Background: this script is to pull my database tables up named yname,username,password,date,comments,works,dworks
 the works and dworks are for people who tryed what came up and then they can judge if it 
works - yes it works
dworks - no it dosent work 
its supposed to be voting sortof well forget about that my problem is on like 40 of this script please help me

```
<php require "br.htm" ?>
<style>
<?php require "styles.css" ?>
</style>
<?php

$host="host"; // Host name 
$username="name"; // Mysql username 
$password="pass"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="dbname"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="passes"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// select record from mysql 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table background='https://lh6.ggpht.com/DFABQFuYSXLBiB6qlvDPfOONOUxCiwM6_S-dHnjW82iognQToTkORsy7RVXsAz0Y23w=w705' width='50%'>
<tr>
<th align='center'>Submition By</th><th align='center'>ScreenName</th><th align='center'>Password</th><th align='center'>Does This Work?</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td background='transparent' align='left'><i><b><? echo $rows['yname']; ?> </b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['username']; ?></b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='right'><i><b><? echo $rows['password']; ?></b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='right'><i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes<? echo $rows['works']; ?></b></i></td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>

</table>

<?php
// close connection; 
mysql_close();
?>
<center>
```

i dont want to re-style the page but if i have to i will.. if you see what is wrong please make a post below and tell me what line its on and how to correct it please then ill come back and let u know if it works :) thank you

Comment: Search first, ask after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error means your query failed. `mysql_query()` returns `false` if an error occurred, you are then passing `false` to `mysql_fetch_array()` which is triggering the error message.

Your query could be failing due to a missing/wrong table or field. To see the detailed error, print out the result of `mysql_error()`.

---

The `mysql_*` library is deprecated. It is recommended to upgrade to MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Change this line `$result=mysql_query($sql);` to `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to verify it's your query

Comment: thanks Toby i figured it out i had id named # in database for some reason :)

Comment: Bless you @Toby that helped me out a lot.